# Brightness control missing when using Nvidia drivers but re-appears with X.Org

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, 18.04, brightness

FYI Linux newbie, still learning. So have Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual boot machine, which has a 980m, running with Nvidia drivers but I sacrifice brightness control.

However I get the setting back when using x.org BUT machine has an issue where if it falls asleep, it will never wake up, well the screen won't.

I've seen the brightness issue during my search but these results vary from distro versions and would not rather use the commands which may have depreciated or changed.

So is there a one great fix or do I need to tinker with the files or am I stuck to using x.org which gives me brightness sliders but set the machine never to sleep?

EDIT: Well, gone back to x.org, an error appeared soon after I logged back in relating to "/usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume" so going to look into that more

EDIT2: Well running, sudo apt-get purge apport
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install apport

has removed my brightness control even from x.org,

EDIT3: Well enabled nvidia, then disabled it and back down to x.org which has restored brightness control so I'll be closing this post and making a new one about sleep issues.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

then add:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, tried, made the change but no brightness when using Nvidia